# function file/2 undefined in generated code from Erlang's yecc

Tags: erlang, bnf, yecc

When using Erlang's [`yecc`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html) to generate a parser from a grammar definition, my file compiled successfully with `yecc:file/1`, but the generated code wouldn't compile, with the following error:

```
src/parse.yrl:364:2: function file/2 undefined
```

I searched for `file` in the generated code, but found only module attributes `-file(...)` over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by me failing to include a period `.` at the end of a function defined in the `Erlang code.` section of my `.yrl` file. It seems that the code compiles fine from `yecc`, but the lack of a period on the end of a function definition meant that the `-file(...)` annotation was being treated like a function call after a minus `-` sign.

The generated code looked like this:

```erl
function(A, B, C) ->
    {A, B, C}
-file("path/to/file", 0)
```

After adding the period to the end of the function in the `.yrl` file, the code compiled successfully.